# How to reshape Arrays quickly

Tags: julia

In the following code I am using the Julia Optim package for finding an optimal matrix with respect to an objective function.
Unfortunately the provided optimize function only supports vectors, so I have to transform the matrix to a vector before passing it to the optimize function, and also transform it back when using it in the objective function.

```
function opt(A0,X)    
    I1(A) = sum(maximum(X*A,1))

    function transform(A)
      # reshape matrix to vector
      return reshape(A,prod(size(A)))
    end

    function transformback(tA)
      # reshape vector to matrix
      return reshape(tA, size(A0))
    end

    obj(tA) = -I1(transformback(tA))
    result = optimize(obj, transform(A0), method = :nelder_mead)
    return transformback(result.minimum)
end
```

I think Julia is allocating new space for this every time and it feels slow, so what would be a more efficient way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like the reshape function, but instead of creating/copying to a new object just offering a reshaped interface to the already existent data?

Comment: It does offer an interface to the existing data, but because `Array{Float64,1}` is a different type than `Array{Float64, 2}`, you have to have a new object as a wrapper even if the underlying data are the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So long as arrays contain elements that are considered immutable, which includes all primitives, then elements of an array are contained in 1 big ***contiguous*** blob of memory.  So you can break dimension rules and simply treat a 2 dimensional array as a 1-dimensional array, which is what you want to do.  So you don't need to reshape, but I don't think reshape is your problem

### Arrays are column major and contiguous

Consider the following function

```
function enumerateArray(a)
   for i = 1:*(size(a)...)
      print(a[i])
   end
end
```

This function multiplies all of the dimensions of **a** together and then loops from 1 to that number assuming **a** is one dimensional.

When you define a as the following

```
julia> a = [ 1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  
 3  4
 5  6
```

The result is

```
julia> enumerateArray(a)
135246
```

This illustrates a couple of things.

1. Yes it actually works
2. Matrices are stored in column-major format

### reshape

So, the question is why doesn't reshape use that fact?  Well it does.  Here's the julia source for reshape in [array.c](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/array.c#L150)

```
a = (jl_array_t*)allocobj((sizeof(jl_array_t) + sizeof(void*) + ndimwords*sizeof(size_t) + 15)&-16);
```

So yes a new array is created, but the only the new dimension information is created, it points back to the original data which is not copied.  You can verify this simply like this:

```
 b = reshape(a,6);

julia> size(b)
(6,)

julia> size(a)
(3,2)

julia> b[4]=100
100

julia> a
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  100
 3    4
 5    6
```

So setting the 4th element of **b** sets the (1,2) element of **a**.

As for overall slowness

```
I1(A) = sum(maximum(X*A,1))
```

will create a new array.

You can use a couple of macros to track this down  **@profile** and **@time**.  Time will additionally record the amount of memory allocated and can be put in front of any expression.

For example

```
julia> A = rand(1000,1000);
julia> X = rand(1000,1000);
julia> @time sum(maximum(X*A,1))
elapsed time: 0.484229671 seconds (8008640 bytes allocated)
266274.8435928134
```

The statistics recorded by **@profile** are output using **Profile.print()**

Answer (score 1):

Also, most methods in Optim actually allow you to supply Arrays, not just Vectors. You could generalize the `nelder_mead` function to do the same.